# Cleveref and postnote

Tags: cleveref

A small question concerning the customization of `cleveref`.

I'm trying to set the format of `\cref` to get "(Fig. 1)".

I managed to get what I want with

```
\crefformat{figure}{(#2fig.~#1#3)}
```

Nevertheless, I sometimes need to add a note to this reference and I would like to get a reference of the type: "(Fig. 1, n ° 1)".

Is it possible to add a postnote in the same way as in biblatex `\cite[posnote]{bib}`?

I could not find what I wanted in the official documentation or on the website.

Thank you!

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\providecommand{\numero}{n\textsuperscript{o}\nobreakspace}

\crefformat{figure}{(#2fig.~#1#3)}

\begin{document}  
    \captionof{figure}{Je suis une legende}\label{legende} 
I would like this: (fig.~1, \numero 1)

Not this \cref{legende}, \numero 1

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a workaround, you could create a special command with the desired behaviour:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\providecommand{\numero}{n\textsuperscript{o}\nobreakspace}

\crefformat{figure}{#2fig.~#1#3}

\usepackage{etoolbox}   
\newcommand{\crefp}[2][]{%
    (\cref{#2}%
    \ifstrempty{#1}{}{%
            , #1%
        }%
    )%
}

\begin{document}  
    \captionof{figure}{Je suis une legende}\label{legende} 

I would like this: (fig.~1, \numero 1)

Not this \crefp[\numero 1]{legende}

\crefp{legende}


\end{document}
```

[image]

---

This approach also works for a list of labels:

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\providecommand{\numero}{n\textsuperscript{o}\nobreakspace}

\crefformat{figure}{#2fig.~#1#3}

\usepackage{etoolbox}   
\newcommand{\crefp}[2][]{%
    (\cref{#2}%
    \ifstrempty{#1}{}{%
            , #1%
        }%
    )%
}

\begin{document}  
    \captionof{figure}{Je suis une legende}\label{legende} 
    \captionof{figure}{Je suis une legende}\label{legendee} 

\crefp[\numero 1]{legende,legendee}

\crefp{legende,legendee}

\cref{legende,legendee}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Little new problem. In the case where I refer to several labels, the reference no longer works.
\crefp{lab1,,lab2}
I obtain the first but "??" for the second :(.
Any idea ?

Comment: @Axelito Works fine for me. Please consider asking a new questions which includes a MWE that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Oops, I said nothing, I put a space in my document between the comma and the label ... I'm a little foolish